# cant open ejabberd webadmin

Tags: debian, ejabberd

I have new Debian 9.

I have new ejabberd from repos, without any errors.

```
root@mail:~# apt install ejabberd 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Будут установлены следующие дополнительные пакеты:
  erlang-goldrush erlang-jiffy erlang-lager erlang-p1-cache-tab erlang-p1-iconv erlang-p1-stringprep erlang-p1-tls erlang-p1-utils erlang-p1-xml erlang-p1-yaml erlang-p1-zlib erlang-proper
Предлагаемые пакеты:
  apparmor apparmor-utils imagemagick yamllint ejabberd-contrib erlang-luerl erlang-p1-oauth2 erlang-p1-mysql erlang-p1-pam erlang-p1-pgsql erlang-p1-sip erlang-p1-stun erlang-p1-sqlite3
  erlang-redis-client
НОВЫЕ пакеты, которые будут установлены:
  ejabberd erlang-goldrush erlang-jiffy erlang-lager erlang-p1-cache-tab erlang-p1-iconv erlang-p1-stringprep erlang-p1-tls erlang-p1-utils erlang-p1-xml erlang-p1-yaml erlang-p1-zlib
  erlang-proper
обновлено 0, установлено 13 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
Необходимо скачать 910 kB/4 728 kB архивов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 8 346 kB.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
Пол:1 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-proper amd64 1.2+dfsg-1 [271 kB]
Пол:2 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-jiffy amd64 0.14.8+dfsg-1 [55,7 kB]
Пол:3 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-goldrush amd64 0.1.9-2 [59,2 kB]
Пол:4 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-lager amd64 3.2.4-1 [188 kB]
Пол:5 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-p1-utils amd64 1.0.5-3 [105 kB]
Пол:6 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-p1-cache-tab amd64 1.0.4-2 [18,6 kB]
Пол:7 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-p1-iconv amd64 1.0.2-2 [8 418 B]
Пол:8 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-p1-stringprep amd64 1.0.6-2 [30,5 kB]
Пол:9 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-p1-tls amd64 1.0.7-2+deb9u1 [28,2 kB]
Пол:10 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-p1-xml amd64 1.1.15-2 [121 kB]
Пол:11 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-p1-yaml amd64 1.0.6-2 [13,3 kB]
Пол:12 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian stretch/main amd64 erlang-p1-zlib amd64 1.0.1-4 [12,3 kB]
Получено 910 kБ за 1с (740 kБ/c)           
Предварительная настройка пакетов ...
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-proper.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 76997 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/00-erlang-proper_1.2+dfsg-1_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-proper (1.2+dfsg-1) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-jiffy.
Подготовка к распаковке …/01-erlang-jiffy_0.14.8+dfsg-1_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-jiffy (0.14.8+dfsg-1) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-goldrush.
Подготовка к распаковке …/02-erlang-goldrush_0.1.9-2_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-goldrush (0.1.9-2) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-lager.
Подготовка к распаковке …/03-erlang-lager_3.2.4-1_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-lager (3.2.4-1) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-p1-utils.
Подготовка к распаковке …/04-erlang-p1-utils_1.0.5-3_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-p1-utils (1.0.5-3) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-p1-cache-tab.
Подготовка к распаковке …/05-erlang-p1-cache-tab_1.0.4-2_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-p1-cache-tab (1.0.4-2) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-p1-iconv.
Подготовка к распаковке …/06-erlang-p1-iconv_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-p1-iconv (1.0.2-2) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-p1-stringprep.
Подготовка к распаковке …/07-erlang-p1-stringprep_1.0.6-2_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-p1-stringprep (1.0.6-2) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-p1-tls.
Подготовка к распаковке …/08-erlang-p1-tls_1.0.7-2+deb9u1_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-p1-tls (1.0.7-2+deb9u1) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-p1-xml.
Подготовка к распаковке …/09-erlang-p1-xml_1.1.15-2_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-p1-xml (1.1.15-2) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-p1-yaml.
Подготовка к распаковке …/10-erlang-p1-yaml_1.0.6-2_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-p1-yaml (1.0.6-2) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета erlang-p1-zlib.
Подготовка к распаковке …/11-erlang-p1-zlib_1.0.1-4_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается erlang-p1-zlib (1.0.1-4) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета ejabberd.
Подготовка к распаковке …/12-ejabberd_16.09-4_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается ejabberd (16.09-4) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-p1-zlib (1.0.1-4) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-p1-utils (1.0.5-3) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-p1-stringprep (1.0.6-2) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-p1-yaml (1.0.6-2) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-goldrush (0.1.9-2) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для systemd (232-25+deb9u4) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для man-db (2.7.6.1-2) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-p1-iconv (1.0.2-2) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-p1-tls (1.0.7-2+deb9u1) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-proper (1.2+dfsg-1) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-p1-cache-tab (1.0.4-2) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-jiffy (0.14.8+dfsg-1) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-p1-xml (1.1.15-2) …
Настраивается пакет erlang-lager (3.2.4-1) …
Настраивается пакет ejabberd (16.09-4) …
Generating SSL certificate /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem...

Creating config file /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml with new version
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ejabberd.service → /lib/systemd/system/ejabberd.service.
Обрабатываются триггеры для systemd (232-25+deb9u4) …
```

I tried to get WEBADMIN, but i get an error:

> http://192.168.1.178:5280/admin

And:

```
root@mail:~# systemctl status ejabberd.service 
● ejabberd.service - A distributed, fault-tolerant Jabber/XMPP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ejabberd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-07-26 14:55:17 MSK; 14min ago
     Docs: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/docs/
 Main PID: 16724 (beam.smp)
    Tasks: 19 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ejabberd.service
           ├─16724 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-8.2.1/bin/beam.smp -K true -P 250000 -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/lib/ejabberd -- -sname ejabberd -noshell -noinput -noshell -
           └─16743 erl_child_setup 32768
```

Also:

```
root@mail:~# netstat -tulpn | grep beam
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41779           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16724/beam.smp      
tcp6       0      0 :::5269                 :::*                    LISTEN      16724/beam.smp      
tcp6       0      0 :::5280                 :::*                    LISTEN      16724/beam.smp      
tcp6       0      0 :::5222                 :::*                    LISTEN      16724/beam.smp
```

And i have permit rules in iptables:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:xmpp-client
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5223
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5280
```

So i have few question:

q1) Is it normal that out-of-the-box it is not working?

q2) It seems to me, that i should to modify IPv4 port listening this product? (/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml) or what?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Funny, use

```
https://
```

instead of

```
http://
```

Have a nice day!